# How do I enable fips when I have fips-updates enabled?

Tags: 20.04, kernel, ubuntu-advantage

For some reason, https://ubuntu.com/blog/running-fips-140-workloads-on-ubuntu in the enable fips section instructed to do a "ua enable fips-updates" instead of ua enable fips and now my system is not compliant. The reason for this is because the compliance scripts look for a file called fips_enabled inside /proc/sys/crypto with a variable "fips" set equal to 1. Enabling/installing fips will do this for you automatically but enabling fips-updates does not.

Some things that I have tried.
Set fips=1 in /etc/default/grub in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
Disable fips-updates, uninstalling ua, reinstalling ua, and then trying to enable fips, but the system detects that fips-updates was previously allowed on the system and therefore fips cannot be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enabling FIPS with UA client, `fips` is FIPS Certified, and `fips-updates` is FIPS Compliant.

Alas, once you go from `fips` to `fips-updates` you can't go backwards to `fips` again. It's a 1 way journey.

The distinction between FIPS Certified and FIPS Compliant, is that `fips-updates` has the benefit of security patching, and even supports live kernel patching through Livepatch.

If you need to audit your fleet to determine what FIPS configuration has been applied where, you can [audit UA Client FIPS configurations at scale with Landscape](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/audit-ua-client-fips-configurations-at-scale-with-landscape#3-landscape-scripts)

Comment: The thing is, if I went from fips to fips-updates, I'm pretty sure my system would be compliant. But because I went straight to enabling fips-updates, I don't get that extra step that puts a line in the kernel. Guess my only bet would be to reinstall the system and then enable fips?

Comment: You don't need to worry about leapfrogging here. There are different package pinning policies for `fips` and `fips-updates`, and you can safely enable `fips-updates` without having ever enabled `fips` before. Enabling `fips` first wouldn't be a good use of your time, because it isn't a prerequisite. Is there something you are seeing or noticing that makes you believe this to be the case?

Comment: I believe it is because "The reason for this is because the compliance scripts look for a file called fips_enabled inside /proc/sys/crypto with a variable "fips" set equal to 1."
I believe enabling fips does this, and enabling fips-updates does not.

Comment: It worked fine for me with UA Client version 27.5~18.04.1. My steps were: 

1.) Use Multipass to launch a fresh Ubuntu instance. 
2.) Ran `ua attach <token>`, confirmed FIPS was not enabled with `ua status`. Also checked to ensure the `/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled` file did not exist. 
3.) Performed a `sudo ua enable fips-updates` followed by a `sudo reboot` when it recommended a reboot to finalize the fips-updates installation. 

Upon reboot I checked for the `/proc/sys/crypto/fips_enabled` file (and its contents was "1").

Comment: You are correct. I tried this on a different system and enabling fips-updates creates the fips_enabled and sets it to 1. Perhaps there is something different going on in the first system that I tested.. Thank you.